# Customize xlviewer.aspx in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, excel-services

We're using SharePoint 2010 and I have a requirement to hide the breadcrumb links at the top of the `xlviewer.aspx` page for Excel Services. I've found quite a bit of documentation on how to customize the `xlviewer.aspx` page on SP 2007, but nothing for SP 2010. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to hide the breadcrumb navigation on the `xlviewer.aspx` page. I added the following CSS directly in the page:

```
<style type="text/css">
BODY #s4-mini-titlearea {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following CSS?

www.codeproject.com/Tips/363642/Hiding-Title-Bar-Navigation-Breadcrumb-section-in

```
<style type="text/css">
BODY #s4-leftpanel {
    DISPLAY: none
}
.s4-ca {
    MARGIN-LEFT: 0px
}
.s4-title {
    DISPLAY: none
}</style>
```

Comment: It looks like the `xlviewer.aspx` file uses the `minimalv4.css` stylesheet, so the classes are different than in this CSS -- but thanks for leading me in a good direction.

Comment: If you use Firebug for Firefox or IE Developer Tools, you can mouse over the objects to find the classes of the divs you want to hide.